# Symfony 4 - use simple entity injector in route

Tags: symfony

Using Symfony 4.0, I try to inject my entity using my route.

Here is my controller :

```
   /**
     * @param TblResidence $tblResidence
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @Route("/residences/{res_id}", name="residences_view")
     */
    public function view(TblResidence $tblResidence)
    {
        return $this->render('residences/view.html.twig', [
            'residence' => $tblResidence,
        ]);
    }
```

And here is my entity :

```
/**
 * TblResidence
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="tbl_residence", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="syn_id", columns={"syn_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="uti_id_crea", columns={"uti_id_crea"}), @ORM\Index(name="uti_id_maj", columns={"uti_id_maj"}), @ORM\Index(name="exp_id", columns={"exp_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="res_code", columns={"res_code"}), @ORM\Index(name="mar_id", columns={"mar_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="not_id", columns={"not_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="seg_id", columns={"seg_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TblResidence
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="res_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $resId;

    ....
```

And for now I got this error :

> Controller "App\Controller\ResidencesController::view()" requires that
>   you provide a value for the "$tblResidence" argument. Either the
>   argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default
>   value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument
>   after this one.

I don't think I need to use ParamConverter (to be honest, I didn't find docs for SF4 about it) since I just want to match using the ID. I tried `resId`, `id`, `res_id` as param name, still same error.

Do I miss something (yes I do of course) ?

**EDIT**

I installed this package from composer :

```
composer require sensio/framework-extra-bundle
```

And now it works, the ParamConverter seems to depend on this package.

More informations : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html

Comment: Do you have installed the `sensio/framework-extra-bundle` package?

Comment: Look my edit, I solved my problem using the extra bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Your parameter have to be called resId like in your entity. If you want to use a different name, you have to be explicit with the @ParamConverter annotation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#doctrine-converter

```
/**
 * @param TblResidence $tblResidence
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 * @Route("/residences/{resId}", name="residences_view")
 */
public function view(TblResidence $tblResidence = null)
{
    return $this->render('residences/view.html.twig', [
        'residence' => $tblResidence,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Using this, `$tblResidence` is null in my controller

Comment: Putting " = null" after the parameter of the function means that the $id could be null or not in your database table. That's why I avoid to use paramConverter when the id is optionnal

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to set your `$tblResidence` argument nullable because here your typehinting requires that you provide a `TblResidence` and nothing else.

Something like this should do the job (where `$tblResidence` is your entity identifier).

```
/**
 * @param TblResidence $tblResidence
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 * @Route("/residences/{tblResidence}", name="residences_view")
 */
public function view(TblResidence $tblResidence = null)
{
    return $this->render('residences/view.html.twig', [
        'residence' => $tblResidence,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: If I use your code, and in my view : `href="{{ path('residences_view', {'tblResidence' : residence.getResId}) }}" ...`, I got this error : `Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Controller\ResidencesController::view() must be an instance of App\Entity\TblResidence or null, string given`

Comment: Yes you can directly pass your whole `tblResidence` object instead of its id.

Answer (score 0):

I installed this package from composer :

> composer require sensio/framework-extra-bundle

And now it works, the ParamConverter seems to depend on this package.

More informations : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html

And use the name of the field from Entity :

```
   /**
     * @param TblResidence $tblResidence
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @Route("/residences/{resId}", name="residences_view")
     */
    public function view(TblResidence $tblResidence)
    {
        return $this->render('residences/view.html.twig', [
            'residence' => $tblResidence,
        ]);
    }
```