# Cannot autowire argument $post of "App\Controller\BlogController::postById()"

Tags: php, symfony

I am a beginner in symfony, I followed a symfony 4.2 training, I want to have a post with id but it gives me error: `Cannot autowire argument $post of "App\Controller\BlogController::postById()": it references class "App\Entity\Post" but no such service exists`. knowing that in training it works well

I am a beginner in symfony, I followed a symfony 4.2 training, I want to have a post with id but it gives me error: `Cannot autowire argument $post of "App\Controller\BlogController::postById()": it references class "App\Entity\Post" but no such service exists`. knowing that in training it works well

**BlogController.php**

```
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Entity\Post;


/**
    * @Route("/post/{id}", requirements={ "id" : "\d+" }, name="get_one_post_by_id")
    * 
    */
    public function postById(Post $post){
        return $this->json($post);
    }
```

**config/services.yaml**

```
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.1",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.11",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.11",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
        "symfony/console": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.2.*"
    },
```

Comment: Can you show your `config/services.yaml`? Can you also check `bin/console debug:autowiring BlogController` if the controller is tagged with[controller.argument_value_resolver](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/argument_value_resolver.html)? Specifically your controllers must be tagged and you need to make sure entities are not registered as services, e.g. `bin/console debug:autowiring Post` should not return a service.

Comment: @dbrumann thx for u answer i edit my code i add `services.yaml`

Comment: That looks fine. Do you have Doctrine ORM installed? Try running the following command: `composer require orm` or `composer require doctrine/orm doctrine/doctrine-bundle`, if you do not use symfony/flex in your project.

Comment: @dbrumann i try to run the `composer require doctrine/orm doctrine/doctrine-bundle` command it gives me error, then i run the `composer require orm` command it works, but the error stays the same

Comment: Do you know if Doctrine is configured? Can you check if you have a `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`? Could you maybe also add the content of your `composer.json` to the question?

Comment: @dbrumann yes i have a `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`.but when i run `php bin/console` its give me error

Comment: Read the error. Show us your ` "App\Entity\Post"` class if it even exists and check if it exists under the correct namespace.

Comment: @Domagoj I check everything is correct

Comment: Based on the previous comments I really don't think you have installed Symfony 4 properly.  In particular, Doctrine entities are injected using what is known as a Param Converter which is implemented by the sensio/framework-extra-bundle.  I don't see it in your composer.json file and you say you keep getting errors when running various commands.  Start over and install a fresh Symfony 4.4 project with: "symfony new --full --version=lts project"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony 4 - use simple entity injector in route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678775/symfony-4-use-simple-entity-injector-in-route)

Answer (score 0):

It look like missing annotation for your entity.

Comment: In the future you should probably consider adding just a bit more detail to your answers.  You should also be aware that for the basic case shown ib the question, no additional annotation is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" installed.
run:

```
composer require sensio/framework-extra-bundle
```

and check config/bundles.php have Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle

Answer (score -1):

Try to clear an annotation cache by command

```
bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

Comment: Nice idea perhaps but unless you know for a fact that this is the problem then a comment might have been more appropriate.  Also, just for reference, routing annotation is not really part of Doctrine so it's highly unlikely that this will work.